# Symfony CMF Could not find the manager name parameter in the container

Tags: php, symfony

I'm just using symfony for the first time.. I had it working with my own controller etc. I tried installing CMF and i get the following error.

```
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not find the manager name parameter in the container. Tried the following parameter names: "cmf_menu.manager_name", "doctrine_phpcr.odm.default_document_manager" in /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php(181): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\RegisterMappingsPass->getManagerName(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php(149): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\RegisterMa in /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php on line 235
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                                                
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not find the manager name parameter in the container. Tried the following parameter names: "cmf_menu.manager_name", "doctrine_phpcr.odm.defa  
  ult_document_manager" in /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php:235                                                   
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  #0 /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php(181): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\RegisterMap  
  pingsPass->getManagerName(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))                                                                                                                                                                
  #1 /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php(149): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\RegisterMa   
  in /var/www/vhosts/admin/symfonycmf.ab-uk.com/htdocs/symfonycmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterMappingsPass.php on line 235
```

Can someone explain what step i'm missing?

config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true








# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'



sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:

        # Some block with different templates
        #acme.demo.block.demo:
        #    templates:
        #       - { name: 'Simple', template: 'AcmeDemoBundle:Block:demo_simple.html.twig' }
        #       - { name: 'Big',    template: 'AcmeDemoBundle:Block:demo_big.html.twig' }






doctrine:   
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: 'localhost'
                #port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: 'symfonycmf'
                user: 'root'
                password: '123456'
                charset: UTF8

    #document_managers:
    #    default:
    #        auto_mapping: true            

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~



cmf_routing:
    dynamic:
        route_provider_service_id: app.route_provider




# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

service.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'



    app.menu_referrer_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\CreateMenuItemFromMenuListener
        arguments: ['@knp_menu.menu_provider']
        tags:
            name: kernel.event_listener
            event: cmf_menu.create_menu_item_from_node
            method: onCreateMenuItemFromNode
```

appkernal.php

```
$bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            // Dependencies of the CmfBlockBundle
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),



            // Dependencies of the CmfMenuBundle
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\CmfRoutingBundle(),
            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\CmfCoreBundle(),
            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle\CmfMenuBundle(),
            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\CmfContentBundle(),
            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\BlockBundle\CmfBlockBundle(),



            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];
```

Comment: Did you install the package with composer?

Comment: Yes I added these to composer.json 
`"doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.3.5",` 
`"sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.0",` 
` "sonata-project/block-bundle": "3.3.2",` 
`"symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "2.0.0"`

Comment: And you also installed the packages afterwards? By doing composer install

Comment: Yes thats when I get the error

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your services.yml:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.menu_referrer_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\CreateMenuItemFromMenuListener
        arguments: ['@knp_menu.menu_provider']
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: cmf_menu.create_menu_item_from_node
                method: onCreateMenuItemFromNode
```

Comment: Im assuming that 'Could not find the manager name parameter in the container'  is the cause of the  clearcache error rather than the other way round

Comment: @JimPhillips Maybe try creating a new project following the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/book/installation.html

Comment: Good plan, I think that starting again is the way forward....Would be interesting to know what the issue was

Comment: @JimPhillips Not sure what went wrong, maybe you need to start the project in a specific way.